# FakeRequest returns 404

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I am trying to test a login form handler using Play! however I always get 404 as the status code when executing the test.

```
@Test
public void testAuthenticate() {
    HashMap<String, String[]> formData = new HashMap<>();
    String[] email = {"admin@domain.com"};
    String[] password = {"password123"};
    formData.put("email", email);
    formData.put("password", password);
    Http.RequestBuilder request = Helpers.fakeRequest("POST", "/app-service/login").bodyFormArrayValues(formData);

    Result result = route(request, maxTimeout);

    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals(OK, result.status());
}
```

In my routes I have this

```
POST    /app-service/login                      @controllers.AuthenticationController.authenticate()
```

Is the URI that I enter in the FakeRequest contrusctor bad or is there something else that I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's an old question, I had the exact same issue and found the solution. It was in how I was running my test.

So the main problem I found was modifications to the routes file were not being pickup. My test all passed once I did a `sbt run`to manually test my API.

The issue was in my IntelliJ SBT settings. To fix everything (meaning ensure that when IntelliJ build my project, it actually calls `sbt compile` in background), simply check 'Use SBT shell for build and import' in your 'Build, Execution, Deployment/Build Tools/SBT' setting window and voilà!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going on a different approach to test Form Data in Play framework. Maybe not as elegant, but it does the trick.

```
@Test
public void testAuthenticate() {
    HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
    formData.put("email", "admin@domain.com");
    formData.put("password", "password123");
    Http.RequestBuilder request = new Http.RequestBuilder().bodyForm(formData);

    Helpers helpers = new Helpers();
    Callable<Result> callable = new Callable() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            F.Promise promise = controller.authenticate();
            return promise.get(maxTimeout);
        }
    };

    Result result = helpers.invokeWithContext(request, callable);

    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals(OK, result.status());
}
```